# the selectionChanged is executed twice, why?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a WPF application that use MVVM pattern. I have a dataGrid and I use also MVVM Light to convert the event to commad the event selectionChanged and I pass the parameter SelectionChangedEventArgs.

I have set the selection mode to extended, because I would like to select many rows in the data grid.

When I select only one row, it works fine, but if I use ctrl pr shift to select many rows, then the event is executed twice, the first one has the rows that I select, so the property AddedItems of the parameter has the items  selected and removedItems is empty. How ever, In the second execution the addedItems is empty and removedItems has items.

Why if I am selecting items, not deselecting them?

After that, in my data grid I can see that I have the correct items selected, but in my property of the view model that stores the selectedItems are empty, so the state is not coherent.

The event to commad is one way mode.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to see how many times the event SelectionChanged have raised? Try basic example and subscribe to event directly (via xaml or codebehind), and check that. If the count will be 1, than you have probably found a bug in mvvm light.

Comment: I create a new application and this works as expected. So I have some code in my application that makes to execute twice the event. I have to find it.